# `people reached` decreased in profile view

Tags: discussion

Hi Yesterday I notice that My estimate people reached decrease by **30k** ,

Is there any change that does this ??

There is no reputation change(decrease) in my reputation tab, but still I am wondering why its decrease by 30k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the same as described here: [What happened to the other people? My Impact (people reached) just dropped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251661/what-happened-to-the-other-people-my-impact-people-reached-just-dropped)

> So in the first few days after posting your answer, its score was enough to satisfy the last condition above (Has at least 20% of the total vote count) but as new answers were posted there with more and more votes, you lost the impact.

Comment: Thank you Fabian for answering me at here, so by this logic more votes you get this estimated people based on vote count more than other criteria ??

Comment: I don't understand the question. The point is that answers that have less than 20% of the total vote count of all answers to this question to not count for the "people reach". Your vote count on an answer probably has dropped below that because other answers got more upvotes.